# Django - localized date and time

Tags: python, django, datetime, localization

I'm using Django 1.6 and I have to display a date. The timezone is Guayaquil (-05:00) and I have to get the date as:

```
{
    'fecha': partido.fecha.strftime("%d %B"),
    'hora': partido.fecha.strftime("%T"),
}
```

Expecting: '13 Junio' and '14:00:00' respectively, since that's the time saved and in Guayaquil timezone.

However what I get is the same time in UTC and months names in english: '13 June' and '19:00:00'.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure you time zone in your Django Settings

Choices can be found [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name)

Check in your settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Guayaquil'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
```

Comment: neither does. tried `localtime(partido.fecha).strftime("%d %B")` and it fixed the UTC timezone issue but did not print the month name in spanish.

Comment: What about the OS? What timezone have it configured?

Comment: I don't know. Is Openshift so I think is English. But I have the language set to 'es' in my project. How can I make the strftime respect the selected language?